# How to retrieve all values inside Django Postgres Array Field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-postgresql

I used Django ArrayField with Postgres Database, I read the documentation however I cannot find a method to retreive all values saved inside the array field.

After retrieved the record from database, I want to convert ArrayField type into python list type.

[This is their documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply instanciate the target object and retrieve the information from the attribute name

My model:
I think you want something this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ModelTest(models.Model):
    board = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.IntegerField(),
            size=2,
        ),
        size=2,
    )
```

My test is, first create one object and get the object, next i retrieve board attribute:

[image]

The return is a list of list in python